# Загрузка изображений с сайта в облако Yandex Disk php

Tags: php, fileupload, yandex-disk

Нужна загрузка с сайта на *Yandex Disk*. Начал делать на чистом PHP  и Curl, но столкнулся с проблемой, что не для всех фотографий создаются превью на стороне Яндекса, решил сам делать превьюшки на сервере и выгружать два файла на *Yandex Disk*, минус одна проблема.

Дальше столкнулся с такой проблемой, что некоторые запросы длились более 30 секунд и обрывались, загрузив основное изображение, но не загрузив превью на облако. Решил не морочить голову себе, закомментировал всё и поставил библиотеку `jack-theripper/yandex`. С ней вроде всё отлично, удобно, но проблема с тем, что превью не создаются - осталась.

И также хотелось бы оформить прогресс бар, но я ничего не могу понять с этими слушателями и с тем, как из ajax-файла сделать параллельный вывод в основной, т.к. сейчас у меня вывод при `success`.

Вот AJAX запрос:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'ajaxuploadfiles.php',
    data: fd,
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    type: 'POST',
    success: function (data) {
        $("#test").html(data);
        intface = 1;
        checkprint();
        return 0;
    }
});
```

PHP обработчик ajax-запроса:

```
if(isset($_FILES['img'])) {
    $client = new Arhitector\Yandex\Client\OAuth('***');
    $disk = new Arhitector\Yandex\Disk($client);

    $img = $_FILES['img']['tmp_name'];
    $img_name = $_FILES['img']['name'];

    //проверки изображения, их пропущу

    $path = '/uploads/waiting/' . $_SESSION['order_id'] . '/';
    $resource = $disk->getResource($path . basename($img_name));

    if (!$resource->has()) {
        $resource->upload($img);
    }
}
```

Comment: Или может вообще не мучаться с yandex диском и найти другое облако? или вообще не выгружать всё в облако и есть какая-то альтернатива?
Просто для манёвренности сайта нужно 50-100Гб под картинки, и я думаю, что с этой задачей наилучшим способом справится именно облако

Comment: Я думаю тебе будет лучше взять VDS и не волноваться со скоростью загрузки и отдачи файлов. И если тебе нужно будет масштабировать сайт, то проблем с объемом у тебя не возникнет. 50гб - это не такая большая цифра